# Is there a lightweight, system tray application to notify of Exchange mail arrival?

Tags: exchange

My work is on an exchange server but I don't get that much email these days so I don't want to keep Outlook open all day. But I do want to be notified immediately when I get new mail. Is there an app that can handle this?

Comment: Does the Exchange server have Web Access enabled? That would be good to know, as it will limit your options if it's not enabled.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This](http://www.slipstick.com/addins/notify.asp) page contains a whole list of potential options. I recommend [OWANotify](http://www.owanotify.com/) also mentioned on the list.

Comment: i saw OWANotify but it hasn't been updated since 2006?

Comment: Active development has just started again, I have however used it with 2007 exchange with very little issues. There is quite a few other good options as well. With 6GB of RAM running Outlook all day has never really been an issue for me. Also we can access our mail from our phones so I rarely need to access mail on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Outlook Web app that can be set up for exchange and log into your exchange account via the web browser. When new mail comes in you would still get a taskbar notification (at least I have when I used Outlook Web in the past).

Note: I can't guarantee that it will work with Firefox or other browsers. I tend to only use IE for my Outlook Web stuff because it just looks better on IE than other browsers IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

I have Outlook set to hide when minimized. It resides in the system tray and lets me know when mail has arrived. That seems to fulfill the requirements.